# How to write nullable columns where conditions are set by parameters - Google Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

If I have a table

> **Goods** have a **nullable** column **receivedStockId**

```
receivedStockId INT64
```

I cannot write a select-statement like below:

```
select * from Goods where receivedStockId=@receivedStockId
```

My current solution is:

```
select * from Goods where receivedStockId in UNNEST([@receivedStockId])
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: What happens when you run the first query? It looks like it should work: NULL = something evaluates to NULL, which is not true per https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/functions-and-operators#operators

Comment: Thank you @TomAyles... I made mistake, and I did not specify type to the parameter:
types.receivedStockId = 'int64'